# Recursive Pascal in Scheme - Unable to find the correct algorithm

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, pascals-triangle

```
(define (pascal x y)
  (cond ((or (<= x 0) (<= y 0) (< x y )) 0)
        ((or (= 1 y) (= x y) ) 1)
        (else (+ (pascal (- x 1) y) (pascal (- x 1) (- y 1))))))
```

This is the function I have for a recursive pascal call that should return the number given the x and y of the triangle.

1
11
121
1331
14641

If I enter pascal 0 0, it should return 1, however it returns 0;
If I enter pascal 4 2, it should return 6, but it returns 3;

Seems like my base is off but I'm not sure how I can change it without ruining the calculation for pascals algorithm. Could someone point me to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, but your conditions aren't quite doing what you think they are. You have something like an off-by-1 error, and you haven't properly split apart your `cond` cases.

```
#lang racket/base
(for ((x (in-range 1 6)))
    (for ((y (in-range (add1 x))))
      (printf "~a " (pascal x y)))
    (newline))
0 1 
0 1 1 
0 1 2 1 
0 1 3 3 1 
0 1 4 6 4 1
```

I make some small changes to your conditions and get this output:

```
(for ((x (in-range 6)))
    (for ((y (in-range (add1 x))))
       (printf "~a " (pascal x y)))
    (newline))
1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1 
1 5 10 10 5 1
```

If this doesn't help I can edit later and put the solution in, but this smells like homework and I don't want to just post a solution.